# Attempting to calculate customer churn w/ PHP and MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a db with a transactions table which stores each transaction with unique id#, customer id#, date and a couple other transaction specific variables. I'm attempting to calculate customer churn thus:

- On given day x there are # of active customers.
- 30 days from given day x the # of active customers (from original day x) we have lost. (so I am trying to track exact customers who have no new transactions)
- I want to be able to run this query for every day in the year.

I don't know if that's clear enough. If not, let me try to rephrase: on any given day in the past I want a list of customer ID's that have an active subscription (our subscriptions are 30 days long) I then want to count how many of those customer ID's renews their subscription within the next 30 days.

I've run a few queries, but everything I am doing seems really inefficient. for example:

```
 //begin pseudo code
 SELECT   CustomerID
 FROM     Transaction
 WHERE    TransactionDate
 <        @SomeDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 AND      TransactionDate
 >        @SomeDate - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

So now I have the customer ID's of those w/ active subscriptions on SomeDate (because any transaction w/in 30 days of SomeDate will have an active subscription) I can then join a new subselect with SomeDate + 30 days and join on CustomerID to get a count of renewed accounts.

The issue(s) I'm concerned with are this: 1. efficiency; I'll have to run this query for each day I want to assess, and I'll only return (if I join) the renewed accounts #--so I'd have to run the query above, then a query w/ join, for each day I want to get active#-renewed#.

What I'd prefer to do (but am apparently incapable of figuring out how) is to run a single query that output a table like this:

```
|SomeDate | Active Cust# | Renewed w/in 30 # |  
---------------------------------------------- 
|  10/1   |     123      |      115          | 
---------------------------------------------- 
|  10/2   |     127      |      112          |
----------------------------------------------  
|  10/3   |     115      |      108          |
----------------------------------------------
```

The key is that the number of renewed accounts is based on comparing to the customer ID's of the Active customer # unique ids. I.e. If Bill (ID#2) and Jim (ID# 4) are the two active customers I want the second "renewed w/in 30 #" list to reflect whether Jim or Bill renews, not whether Bobby Joe bought a subscription during the second period. Thoughts?

Comment: . . I don't usually do this, but if you want to calculate customer churn using SQL, then I highly recommend my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  Two chapters devoted to survival analysis explain exactly what you want to do and how to do it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hey, anything helps! I can get the query to work by hacking together a series of queries and lengthy php logic to make this work. My goal is to find a streamlined way that isn't expensive on resources.